# Fetching User Information from MySQL Error using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, pdo

I have designed an authorization system for a project I'm working on. I'm able to retrieve the user ID from the database, however, I am now trying to get the user name and email for the user. *I am fairly new to PHP, by the way.*

I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

I am confused because

```
$stmt->execute()
```

works just fine, however

```
$stmt2->execute()
```

is failing. I'm sure the problem is something simple, but I cannot figure this out. Here is the PHP code for fetching the info.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT nuewavedb_user_id, nuewavedb_username, nuewavedb_password FROM nuewavedb_users 
                WHERE nuewavedb_username = :nuewavedb_username AND nuewavedb_password = :nuewavedb_password");

    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT nuewavedb_fullname, nuewavedb_email FROM nuewavedb_users 
                WHERE nuewavedb_username = :nuewavedb_username AND nuewavedb_password = :nuewavedb_password");

    /*** bind the parameters ***/
    $stmt->bindParam(':nuewavedb_username', $nuewavedb_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nuewavedb_password', $nuewavedb_password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

    $stmt2->bindParam(':nuewavedb_fullname', $nuewavedb_fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt2->bindParam(':nuewavedb_email', $nuewavedb_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt2->execute();

    /*** check for a result ***/
    $user_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    $nuewavedb_fullname = $stmt2->fetchColumn();
    $nuewavedb_email = $stmt2->fetchColumn(1);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should somehow combine this query especially if it is the same table no need to read twice

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  
                               nuewavedb_user_id
                              ,nuewavedb_username
                              ,nuewavedb_password
                              ,nuewavedb_fullname
                              ,nuewavedb_email  
                       FROM nuewavedb_users 
                       WHERE nuewavedb_username = :nuewavedb_username AND
                             nuewavedb_password = :nuewavedb_password"
        );
```

Then execute and fetch properly:

```
/*** bind the parameters ***/
$stmt->bindParam(':nuewavedb_username', $nuewavedb_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':nuewavedb_password', $nuewavedb_password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

/*** execute the prepared statement ***/
$stmt->execute();

/*** fetch **/
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$nuewavedb_fullname = $row['nuewavedb_fullname'];
$nuewavedb_email = $row['nuewavedb_email'];
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That works perfectly. I just had to add `$user_id = $row['user_id'];` back.

Answer (score 0):

In your statement stmt2 you define 2 parameters : :nuewavedb_username and :nuewavedb_password
But when you bind the parameters you use :nuewavedb_fullname and :nuewavedb_email

You have to use same parameters names